# CanvasJs chart using json data

Tags: javascript, ajax, canvasjs

I am trying to draw CanvasJs chart using data from json file but for some reason it does not work.

The data which I am trying to display are data which is in json file represented as number "####" and value "#"

Please take a look at the code below.

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function() {

var dataPoints = [];

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 animationEnabled: true,
 theme: "light2",
 title: {
  text: "Years"
 },
 axisY: {
  title: "Value",
  titleFontSize: 24
       
 },
 data: [{
  type: "column",
  yValueFormatString: "# Value",
  dataPoints: dataPoints
 }]
});

function addData(data) {
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  dataPoints.push({
   x: new Year(data[i].date),
   y: data[i].value
  });
 }
 chart.render();

}

$.getJSON("https://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries/gbr/indicators/UIS.FOSEP.56.F600?format=json", addData);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to call the json, [$.getJson](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) gives a callback, so once the api gives the data you need to create the dataPoints, once its created create the chart.

I hope the below solution will solve the issue.

**Note**: If required you can add a loader for the mean time while its loading , so the user will know that some thing is loading

```js
const chartCreation = (data) => {
$("#chartContainer").CanvasJSChart({
 animationEnabled: true,
 theme: "light2",
 title: {
  text: "Years"
 },
 axisY: {
  title: "Value",
  titleFontSize: 24
       
 },
 data: [{
  type: "column",
  yValueFormatString: "# Value",
  dataPoints: dataPoints
 }]
});

}

let dataPoints = [];


const addData = (data) => {
  dataPoints = data[1].filter(obj => +(obj.date) >= 2010 && +(obj.date) <=2018 
  ).map(obj => ({x: +(obj.date),
     y: obj.value ? obj.value :  0}))
  // once we have the data pass it to chart creation 
  // function
  chartCreation(dataPoints);
}  



$.getJSON("https://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries/gbr/indicators/UIS.FOSEP.56.F600?format=json", (data) =>{
  // pass the data to function
  addData(data);
});
```

```css
return{
     
   }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

**Updated**

As per the comment, first you can [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) , once you filter you will get a new array where you can return the properties whatever that you want. using [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return what ever the properties.

Comment: thanks, works perfectly. One quick question, how can I filter data in order to display years between 2010 and 2018?

Comment: Welcom matt. Please check the updated post based on the comment. I hope it will solve the issue :)